# Are hypotheticals on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, asking-questions

In my experience, hypotheticals are an important part of legal scholarship.

Are they on topic here? Or does each question need to stem from a practical problem that the asker is having?

(I'll give my position as an answer that can be voted on separately from the question.)

Comment: Can you give an example of the kind of hypothetical you're talking about, then?

Comment: your question sounds like a hypothetical. Is it on topic I still think so.

Answer (score 2):

The evolving custom seems to be that *especially* questions that might stem from a real-world personal legal problem need to be phrased hypothetically.

Related: https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/a/103/10