# How can we attract Quora users from Quora topics related to law?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

Quora has many more lawyers than here. I would love to see this SE burgeon with lawyers! How can we invite, or enthrall, Quora users from these Quora topics?

## [Law](https://www.quora.com/topic/Law?q=law) has 2.6M followers.

[Legal Issues and Law in Everyday Life](https://www.quora.com/topic/Legal-Issues-and-Law-in-Everyday-Life) 1M. [Courts](https://www.quora.com/topic/Courts) 33K.

[Attorneys](https://www.quora.com/topic/Attorneys) 279K. [Legal Ethics](https://www.quora.com/topic/Legal-Ethics) 319K.

[Litigation and Lawsuits](https://www.quora.com/topic/Litigation-and-Lawsuits) 193K. [Court Cases and Trials](https://www.quora.com/topic/Court-Cases-and-Trials) 72K.

[Judiciaries](https://www.quora.com/topic/Judiciaries) 129K, [Judges](https://www.quora.com/topic/Judges) 66K.

[Law Firms](https://www.quora.com/topic/Law-Firms) 93K.

[Contract Law](https://www.quora.com/topic/Contract-Law?q=contract) 46K, [Contracts](https://www.quora.com/topic/Contracts) 69K, [Smart Contracts](https://www.quora.com/topic/Smart-Contracts) 27K, [Employment Law](https://www.quora.com/topic/Employment-Law-3) 64K

[Torts](https://www.quora.com/topic/Torts?q=TORT) 1K.

[Real Estate Law](https://www.quora.com/topic/Real-Estate-Law?q=real%20estate%20law) 2K, [Property Law](https://www.quora.com/topic/Property-Law) 13K.

[Trusts Estate Law](https://www.quora.com/topic/Trusts-and-Estates-Law?q=trusts%20es) 652, [Wills](https://www.quora.com/topic/Estate-Law-and-Wills) 2.3K,

[Business Law](https://www.quora.com/topic/Business-Law) 8K, [Small Business Law](https://www.quora.com/topic/Small-Business-Law) 16K.

[Securities Law](https://www.quora.com/topic/Securities-Law?q=securities%20law) 5K.

## [Intellectual Property](https://www.quora.com/topic/Intellectual-Property-1) has 110k followers.

[Copyright Law](https://www.quora.com/topic/Copyright-Law) has 363.5K followers.

[Intellectual Property Law](https://www.quora.com/topic/Intellectual-Property-Law) 111.7K.

[Trademark Law](https://www.quora.com/topic/Trademark-Law) 65.2K.

[International Copyright Law](https://www.quora.com/topic/International-Copyright-Law) 29.5K.

[United States Patent and Trademark Office](https://www.quora.com/topic/United-States-Patent-and-Trademark-Office) 31.1K.

[Patent Trolls](https://www.quora.com/topic/Patent-Trolls). 23.8K.

---

## [Criminal Law](https://www.quora.com/topic/Criminal-Law) 511K.

[Interacting with Police](https://www.quora.com/topic/Interacting-with-Police) 225K.

[Criminal Prosecution](https://www.quora.com/topic/Criminal-Prosecution) 60K.

## [Laws in the USA](https://www.quora.com/topic/Laws-in-the-United-States-of-America) 133K.

[SCOTUS](https://www.quora.com/topic/U-S-Supreme-Court) 105.1K

[SCOTUS Justices](https://www.quora.com/topic/United-States-Supreme-Court-Justices) 42.2K.

[Constitutions](https://www.quora.com/topic/Constitutions) 95K,  [US Constitutional Law](https://www.quora.com/topic/U-S-Constitutional-Law?q=us%20constitut) 103K, [US Constitution](https://www.quora.com/topic/U-S-Constitution) 85K, [1st Amendment](https://www.quora.com/topic/First-Amendment-to-the-U-S-Constitution) 39K, [2nd Amendment](https://www.quora.com/topic/Second-Amendment-to-the-U-S-Constitution).

[Jurisprudence](https://www.quora.com/topic/Jurisprudence?q=jurisprudence) 5K.

---

[Canada Legal System](https://www.quora.com/topic/Legal-System-of-Canada?q=canada%20legal) 2K. [UK Legal System](https://www.quora.com/topic/Legal-System-of-the-UK?q=uk%20legal) 7K.

## [Laws in India](https://www.quora.com/topic/Laws-in-India) 303K.

[Supreme Court of India](https://www.quora.com/topic/Supreme-Court-of-India) 88K. [Indian Judiciary](https://www.quora.com/topic/Indian-Judiciary) 85K.

Comment: You should explain why you assume that something like that is automatically beneficial. I just glanced at a few posts over there, and found that answers are devoid of sources except for bare mentions of the First or Fifth Amendment. When it comes to ascertaining the reliability of an answer, sources are more useful than statements of the type "*I actually am a lawyer*". It is not even clear that the numbers you bring up support the conclusion that "*Quora has many more lawyers than here*", although ultimately that is irrelevant to the quality and relevance of posts.

Comment: Lastly, a large portion of topics on Quora-law are of the type "*should the law be this way?*", which renders the aforementioned aggregates/numbers meaningless because that type of questions is off-topic for LawSE.

Comment: @IñakiViggers Hi Iñaki. Nice to chat with you. Big fan of your advocacy and assistance here. I recommended this, because I can't think of any other EFFECTIVE marketing ploy! I am JUST trying to entice more legal experts here, like legal academics and professors! If you have a better idea, let me know.

Comment: Related Meta posts: [How do we attract and retain legal experts?](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/q/79/35069), and [. What should our documentation contain?](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10/35069)

Comment: I was going to vote to close as a duplicate of [How do we attract and retain legal experts?](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/q/79/35069), but with hindsight that question is 7 years' old and posted when LawSE was in its infancy so this subject could do with a refresh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is asking for ideas to attract (potentially) knowledge contributors, **not** whether Quora's format, policies and etiquette are compatible or comparable with LawSE.<sup>1</sup>

I'm not familiar with Quora, so generally speaking, social media is probably one of the better ways to promote anything and everything these days - Twitter and Facebook seem to be the front runners but there may be others out there.

I assume, without any basis in fact whatsoever, that there would little or no enthusiasm from Stack Overflow or its subsidiaries to support / finance any sort of marketing campaign. Therefore it would be up to individual users to put in the effort by, for example, sharing links to questions and / or answers in a way that would initiate a conversation and attract contributors - if they don't "fall in line" with our policies and procedures then so be it, but if they do then it's job done.

Also, as well as playing the percentages game by sharing multiple links in this way, there's the added bonus of the [Announcer](https://law.stackexchange.com/help/badges/59/announcer), [Booster](https://law.stackexchange.com/help/badges/60/booster) and even the rarest of rare [Publicist](https://law.stackexchange.com/help/badges/61/publicist) badges.

---

<sup>1</sup>I suspect there are many LawSE users who use different composition styles depending on the particular audience, site, or forum; some may even be active on Quora.

Answer (score 0):

## I don't think this is a good idea.

We have somewhat a citation expectation. Many of those quora answers don't cite anything.

Comment: Why don't we just require citations? Many [questions](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/80541) and answers here also don't cite anything.